# Haskell too many arguments error

Tags: function, haskell, arguments

I am learning Haskell. I am trying to make a function that deletes integers out of a list when met with the parameters of a certain function f.

```
deleteif :: [Int] -> (Int -> Bool) -> [Int]
deleteif x f = if x == [] 
                then [] 
                else if head x == f 
                       then deleteif((tail x) f)  
                       else [head x] ++ deleteif((tail x) f)
```

I get the following errors :

- function tail is applied to two arguments
- 'deleteif' is applied to too few arguments

Comment: Functions in Haskell are called `fun arg1 arg2 ...`, not `fun(arg1, arg2 ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you don't use parentheses to call a function in Haskell.  So you just need to use

```
if f (head x)
   then deleteif (tail x) f
   else [head x] ++ deleteif (tail x) f
```

Comment: I think `head x == f` will be a type error itself ?

Comment: Fixed with my best guess of what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in `deleteif((tail x) f)`

it becomes `deleteif (tail x f)`

so tail gets 2 arguments

and then `deleteif a`

so deleteif gets 1 argument

you want `deleteif (tail x) f`

`head x == f` is wrong you want `f (head x)

you can use pattern matching ,guards and make it more generic

```
deleteif :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
deleteif [] _ = []
deleteif (x:xs) f
    | f x       =     deleteif xs f 
    | otherwise = x : deleteif xs f
```

Comment: A nice idiom: `deleteif (x:xs) f = [x | not (f x)] ++ deleteif xs f`. Also, `deleteif xs f = filter (not . f) xs`

Answer (score 2):

As already said, `deleteif((tail x) f)` is parsed as `deleteif (tail x f)`, which means `tail` is applied to the two arguments `x` and `f`, and the result would then be passed on as the single argument to `deleteif`. What you want is `deleteif (tail x) f`, which is equivalent to `(deleteif (tail x)) f` and what most languages<sup>1</sup> would write `deleteif(tail x, f)`.

This parsing order may seem confusing initially, but it turns out to be really useful in practice. The general name for the technique is [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

- For one thing, it allows you to write dense statements without needing many parentheses – in fact `deleteif (tail x f)` could also be written `deleteif $ tail x f`.
- More importantly, because the arguments don't need to be “encased” in a single tuple, you don't need to supply them all at once but automatically get *partial application* when you apply to only one argument. For instance, you could use this function like that: `deleteif (>4) [1,3,7,5,2,9,7]` to yield `[7,5,9,7]`. This works by partially applying the function<sup>2</sup> `>` to `4`, leaving a single-argument function which can be used to filter the list.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Indeed, this style is *possible* in Haskell as well: just write the signatures of such multi-argument functions as `deleteif :: ([Int], Int->Bool) -> [Int]`. Or write `uncurry deleteif (tail x, f)`. But it's definitely better you get used to the curried style!</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Actually, `>` is an *infix* which behaves a bit different – you can partially apply it to either side, i.e. you can also write `deleteif (4>) [1,3,7,5,2,9,7]` to get `[1,3,2]`.</sub>